# vim insert mode mapping doesn't work

Tags: vim

I want to move one word forward in insert mode.

Why this doesn't work:

```
inoremap ,w <esc>w
```

But this works(back one word):

```
inoremap ,b <esc>b
```

Comment: cannot be reproduced here. but I don't think the mapping is convenient....  it moves to next word, in Normal mode. you may want to take a look `Ctrl-o`

Answer (score 3):

That's because when the cursor is at the beginning of a word, the `<Esc>` will move the cursor one character left (this is a bit unintuitive, but default vi behavior), and the `w` will only move to the original position.

This should work:

```
inoremap ,w <esc>ww
```

### mapping critique

I don't particularly like your mappings:

- starting it with `,` adds a delay whenever you type a comma
- do you really need a command that leaves insert mode and moves the cursor? `<Esc>b` achieves the same and also is two keystrokes (many users remap the `<Esc>` key to be in a less cumbersome position)
- if you really must navigate in insert mode, there's already `<C-Left>` / `<C-Right>`.

Comment: Hi;
Thanks for critique. I was trying to find quick way to move in insert mode. You know that sitation when you open brackets and there is no semicolon at the end of line. Then you have to move to normal mode and press Shift+A to enter semicolon.